# Kafka: Seek() Offset - frequent seeking offset values

Tags: apache-kafka

As we knew, If We want to Consuming Records with Specific Offsets we can do it through Seek() API in Kafka - If we do frequently seek will it be a problem ? What’s is the disadvantage of frequent seeking offset values. Please help me understand .

Answer (score 0):

If you have a use case where you have to do frequent seeks, probably Kafka is not the right tool for it. I would highly recommend to reconsider your choice of Kafka if possible.

That being said, kafka performance comes from sequential disk access (among various other things). Partitions are basically files behind the scenes. So if you are doing seek again and again, you will lose on performance.

Comment: Thanks for your response . Can you please share the reference page for this would be great help for us would be great help .

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_concepts_and_terms